# How to add left navigation bar in mobile wireframe using Balsamiq.

Tags: balsamiq

How to add left navigation bar in mobile wireframe using Balsamiq.

Can anyone tell me the name of that component?

Answer (score 1):

While we don't have a navigator panel built in, you can build one out of rectangles controls.

Or you can just steal the one we built on our [web demo](http://webdemo.balsamiq.com/) by downloading the project. I won't tell anyone. :)

Comment: Thanks Brendan. :D  :D